# Help creating a LINQ to SQL query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm populating a FormView by setting the datasource to an `IQueryable` object that I get by doing a LINQ query. Basically it returns the number of employees that hold a certain "Position" within a certain "Shift".

```
int shiftID = 1;
var shiftCount = from x in context.Employees.Take(1)
                 select new
                 {
                 ManagerCount = ((from p in context.Persons
                              where p.PositionID == 1 && p.ShiftID == shiftID && p.IsEmployee == true
                              select p.PersonId).Count(),
                PartTimeCount = ((from p in context.Persons
                              where (p.PositionID == 2 || p.PositionID == 3) && p.ShiftID == shiftID && p.IsEmployee == true
                              select p.PersonId).Count(),
                 etc, etc...
                 };
```

That part works fine. However, when I want to get the number of employees for **all** shifts, I can't quite figure out how to do it:

```
//Get all shifts 1, 2, and 3
var shiftCount = from x in context.Employees.Take(1)
                 select new
                 {
                 ManagerCount = ((from p in context.Persons
                              where p.PositionID == 1 && (p.ShiftID == 1 || p.ShiftID == 2 || p.ShiftID == 3) && p.IsEmployee == true
                              select p.PersonId).Count()
                 };
```

That doesn't work though because it of course returns 3 values and gives the `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.` error.
So I need to get the sum of the three values returned (it's not always three though, it depends on the position).
I've looked at various ways using Sum and LINQ grouping, but can't quite seem to work it out. Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want **all** shifts, why are you checking `p.ShiftID` at all?

Comment: Well, this is rather embarrassing for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got a few answers for you, but first it seems like you have something wrong with your first part of your query. You're doing `.Take(1)` on `Employees` which will give you only one `x` value. Since you don't use `x` in the remainder of your query then using `Employees` is redundant.

Now, since all of your queries are quite similar I've tried to remove repetition. The first thing to do is to get a common filter for the shifts you are filtering on.

If you have a single shift, use this:

```
int shiftID = 1;
var shifts = new [] { shiftID, };
```

If you have multiple shifts, use this:

```
var shifts = new [] { 1, 2, 3, };
```

Either way you end up with an array of integers representing the shifts you want to filter against. All of the below answers require this `shifts` array.

Then define a query for the employees in those shift, regardless of position for now.

```
var employeesInShifts =
    from p in context.Persons
    where p.IsEmployee
    where shifts.Contains(p.ShiftID)
    select p;
```

So you can then get the shift counts like so:

```
var shiftCount =
    new
    {
        ManagerCount = employeesInShifts
            .Where(p => p.PositionID == 1)
            .Count(),
        PartTimeCount = employeesInShifts
            .Where(p => p.PositionID == 2 || p.PositionID == 3)
            .Count(),
        // etc
    };
```

Perhaps a better alternative for you though, would be to turn the `employeesInShifts` query into a dictionary and then just pluck the values from the dictionary.

```
var employeesInShifts =
    (from p in context.Persons
     where p.IsEmployee
     where shifts.Contains(p.ShiftID)
     group p by p.PositionID into gps
     select new
     {
        PositionID = gps.Key,
        Count = gps.Count(),
     })
    .ToDictionary(pc => pc.PositionID, pc.Count);

var shiftCount =
    new
    {
        ManagerCount = employeesInShifts[1],
        PartTimeCount = employeesInShifts[2] + employeesInShifts[3],
        // etc
    };
```

The downside to this approach is that you really should check that the dictionary has values for each `PositionID` before getting the values.

That can be fixed by introducing an array of position ids that you want the dictionary to have and joining your results on that.

```
var positionIDs = new [] { 1, 2, 3, };

var employeesInShifts =
    (from p in context.Persons
     where p.IsEmployee
     where shifts.Contains(p.ShiftID)
     where positionIDs.Contains(p.PositionID)
     select p).ToArray();

var allPositionEmployeesInShifts =
    from pid in positionIDs
    join p in employeesInShifts on pid equals p.PersonId into gps
    select new
    {
        PositionID = pid,
        Count = gps.Count(),
    };

var countOfPositionID =
    allPositionEmployeesInShifts
        .ToDictionary(x => x.PositionID, x => x.Count);

var shiftCount =
    new
    {
        ManagerCount = countOfPositionID[1],
        PartTimeCount = countOfPositionID[2] + countOfPositionID[3],
        // etc
    };
```

Now that guarantees that your final dictionary will contain the counts of all of the position ids that you are wanting to query.

Let me know if this works or if you really needed to join on the `Employees` table, etc.

Comment: Though I solved it before I got to your solution, I'll definitely be able to use this in another part of the project. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the Group By examples [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336754.aspx#simple1):